# Web API and View in same controller

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm creating a website that will have 50+ optical calculations. I need them accessible via api, but I also need them available in a view. I have a .dll that does the calculations that are accessed in a controller labeled with the name of the "type" of calculations. In this case it's a PrismController that handles all the calculations related to Prism. I'm only showing the Apical Angle calculation.

Is the way I'm doing it optimal in regards to best practices? Before I create 50 of these, I'd like to know if I'm going down the wrong path.

Seems like a lot of code.

The code in the view is what I'm using for one calculation.

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/v1/[controller]")] <----------api route at controller level
public class PrismController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("ApicalAngle/{DegreesDeviation}/{Index}")]
    public ActionResult<PrismModel> ApicalAngle(PrismModel prism)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest(ModelState);

        prism.Result = Prism.ApicalAngle(prism.DegreesDeviation, prism.Index);

        return prism;
    }

    [Route("/[Controller]/[Action]")] <----view route overriding api route
    [HttpGet("ApicalAngle")]
    public IActionResult ApicalAngleCalc()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost("ApicalAngle")]<------- Post that performs calculation
    public ActionResult<PrismModel> ApicalAngleCalc(PrismModel prism)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest(ModelState);

        var dev = prism.DegreesDeviation;

        prism.Result = Prism.ApicalAngle(prism.DegreesDeviation, prism.Index);

        return View(prism);
    }
```

Comment: when you say "I need them accessible via api, but I also need them available in a view", do you mean your 50+ calculation should be available via api?

Comment: My suggestion would be to have two different controllers (one for API & one for views) . That would be one of the best practice. Also please mention the technologies that you are using? I am assuming from the tags that you're using dot.net core & also dont know if you can use something like Ajax in your solution or not.

Comment: @Umang I need the calculations accessible with a GUI (view),but I also want them available to others via an api so they can use them in their own application or website. As far as technologies, I'm using core 2.2 MVC for the views and core 2.2 web api for the api. They've merged into the same controller base class, that's why I have them together.

Comment: It is recommend to split them into mvc controller and web api controller, your current design are too coupling which will make it difficult to maintain. One method should not return view and model result at the same time.

Comment: @TaoZhou One method isn't returning both. One controller is. The api is the top method and the bottom two are for the view. Would this be a situation where Areas would be best?